# is nextAuth with separate express server workable?

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js, jwt, next-auth

I am getting started with Next.js. I have an expres.js backend server which I would like to consume the api using Next.js for client. I am using jwt token to authorize users to access api routes.
When a user signs-in, the user generates this access token and I passed this token via header to the server during request calls.
I want to use the nextAuth which seems easier to use for purely session management to persist user while my jwt access token remains for purely authorizing api requests. In the next.js page folder, under api folder, I created this folder called `auth`, inside that folder, I created this file `[...nextauth].tsx`
I followed a tutorial and came up with this code. Though it is returning the access token for me which I can pass via the header in each api request. However, I want to know if this style is good way to do it:

```
const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },

  providers:[
    CredentialsProvider({
        type: "credentials",
        credentials: {},

       async authorize(credentials, req){
            const { username, password } = credentials as {
                username: string;
                password: string;
              };

              const userData = {
                username: username,
                password: password
              }
              console.log(userData, 'hey')
              const res = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/login`, userData);

            

            if(res?.data){
                console.log(res?.data, userData, 'hey')
                return {
                    id: '1',
                    name: res?.data?.userToken
                }
            }
             return null
              
        }
    })
  ],

  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },


 };


 export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

In this code, I am simply calling my external login api route inside the nextAuth system and returned the response which is the access token from that external api. I could access the access token using   `const { status, data } = useSession();`
When I use `console.log( data?.user?.name)`, I could see the access token and I am sure that I can pass it in header bearer during user's api requests.
Is this strategy okay?